# How to access this item using Beautiful Soup

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access an element in

```
<script type="text/javascript">ReportPopper("http://asd.asd.asd/ReportOutput/asd-asd-41cc-asd-asd.xls");<script>
```

using `beautifulsoup`, unfortunately I'm not sure on how to access the ReportPopper part and assign it to a variable using `Python`

Sorry if this is already answered.
I've tried adding ReportPopper in the find('ReportPopper') and gives me a none element.

```
import requests
import io
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


participation = requests.post(url=report_post_url,data=request_post_report_form,headers=report_post_headers,stream=True)
print(participation)


soup = BeautifulSoup(participation.text, 'html.parser')

for n in soup.find_all('script'):
    javascript = n['ReportPopper']
    print(javascript)
```

I want to get my end result as:

`javascript = "http://asd.asd.asd/ReportOutput/asd-asd-41cc-asd-asd.xls"`

as my output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\John asd\Documents\GitHub\asd.net\testing.py", line 184, in <module>
    javascript = n['ReportPopper']
  File "C:\Users\John asd\asd\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1016, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'ReportPopper'
```

Comment: What is the value of `report_post_url` ?

Comment: Please, check if the element you posted is correct. I mean: `<script type="text/javascript">ReportPopper("http://asd.asd.asd/ReportOutput/asd-asd-41cc-asd-asd.xls");<script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[re.compile()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#re.compile) returns a [regular expression object](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#regular-expression-objects), which means h is a regex object.

The regex object has its own [match](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#re.regex.match) method with the optional pos and endpos parameters:

[regex.match(string[, pos[, endpos]])](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#re.regex.match)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import  re

html = """<script>ReportPopper("http://asd.asd.asd/ReportOutput/asd-asd-41cc-asd-asd.xls");</script>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
script = soup.find_all("script")

pattern = re.compile('ReportPopper(.*);')

for i in script:
    strObj = i.text
    match = pattern.search(strObj)
    if match:
        print(strObj.split("ReportPopper(")[1][:-2])
```

O/P:

```
"http://asd.asd.asd/ReportOutput/asd-asd-41cc-asd-asd.xls"
```

Answer (score 1):

With bs4 4.7.1 you can use :contains if that string is present in the response

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
# r = requests.get(url)
# html - r.content
html = '<script type="text/javascript">ReportPopper("http://asd.asd.asd/ReportOutput/asd-asd-41cc-asd-asd.xls");<script>'
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
s = soup.select_one('script:contains(ReportPopper)').text
url = s.split('"')[1]
print(url)
```

Comment: welcome. Should be a little more efficient than regex.